# Column span in datasheet view

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In Microsoft Access 2010, I have a subform in datasheet view. This subform should display data from two tables. I join the data in an temporary table.

Is it possible to display a specific record´s content across all other columns (column span) like in Excel (merge & center)?

```
|Column 1    | Column 2   | Column 3   |
|--------------------------------------|
|Value 1-1   | Value 1-2  | Value 1-3  |
|                Value 2-1             |
|Value 3-1   | Value 3-2  | Value 3-3  |
|Value 4-1   | Value 4-2  | Value 4-3  |
|                Value 5-1             |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this isn't possible in any native grid-like view in MS Access.

If you want this kind of functionality you'll have to use an ActiveX grid control such as the iGrid from 10tec.